# Custom global variable in typescript

Tags: typescript

i'm trying to assign custom global variable in typescript. and i have my project structure like:

```
- config/
- src/
- types/
  - custom.d.ts
- index.ts
- package.json
- tsconfig.json
```

and inside `custom.d.ts` file is like:

```
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
       customvar: string
    }
  }
}

export default global;
```

and in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  ...,

  "typeRoots": [
    "types"
  ],
  "types": [
    "node"
  ]
}
```

in my `index.ts`, when i tried something like below and run it:

```
global.customvar = "test";
```

it throws error:

```
index.ts:1:8 - error TS2339: Property 'customvar' does not exist on type 'Global & typeof globalThis'.
```

what did i do wrong? my `customvar` even already showed in autocompletion :

[image: autocompletion]

i tried solutions i could find online, but didn't seem to solve my problem. did i miss something? any solution/suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo sorry, that was a typo. and no, that wasn't my problem. thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: did you import your interface to your `index.ts`?

Comment: @firatozcevahir yes, tried it. didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem has been solved. the issue was neither from typescript nor the structure itself. but, it came from `ts-node`. since i used `ts-node` to run my script, there were several missing configs in my setup.

the solutions can be found here: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#help-my-types-are-missing